# Logging with winston

Tags: node.js, logging, winston

```
const tsFormat = () => (new Date()).toLocaleTimeString();
const logger = new (winston.Logger)({
  transports: [
    // colorize the output to the console
    new (winston.transports.Console)({
      timestamp: tsFormat,
      colorize: true,
      level: 'info'
    }),
    new (require('winston-daily-rotate-file'))({
      filename: `${app_config.logfolder}/-${app_config.application[APP_NAME].logfile}`,
      timestamp: tsFormat,
      datePattern: 'dd-MM-yyyy',
      prepend: true,
      handleExceptions: true,
      level:app_config.application[APP_NAME].loglevel
    })
  ]
});
```

I have configured my logger with my desired level. But after that i have to use logger.info or other log levels. So is there any way i can do something like logger.log without specifying log-level because i have already  configured my log level.

It makes no sense after using the log level each time when i have already configured my log-level.

Answer (score 0):

Basically encapsulate your custom logging method in a separate module and reuse it

```
// in MyLogger.js
const tsFormat = () => (new Date()).toLocaleTimeString();
const logger = new (winston.Logger)({
  transports: [
    // colorize the output to the console
    new (winston.transports.Console)({
      timestamp: tsFormat,
      colorize: true,
      level: 'info'
    }),
    new (require('winston-daily-rotate-file'))({
      filename: `${app_config.logfolder}/-${app_config.application[APP_NAME].logfile}`,
      timestamp: tsFormat,
      datePattern: 'dd-MM-yyyy',
      prepend: true,
      handleExceptions: true,
      level:app_config.application[APP_NAME].loglevel
    })
  ]
});

exports.log = function(message) {
     logger.log('info', message);
}

// in consumer.js
var log = require('MyLogger');
log('My log message');
```

Comment: yah thought of that but in that case i have to define my own method log so i can use logger.log() and in that method i have to pass the log level again in main winston  log settings.

Comment: @MASIDDIQUI then you just need to encapsulate your logging method in a reuable module :). See my updated

Comment: thanks @phnkha , I think i should make a pull request in winston, Yah its good to use encapsulation but id does not make a good sense using library.

Comment: As you just want "info" level log, just export "logger.info" function and give whatever name(log, myLog, etc) you want to the variable where you require it. This is same as @phnkha 's answer.